# Convert DataSet with relations to nested json

Tags: c#, json, xml-serialization

I am using c# and i have a DataSet (ds) with 2 Datatables (dt1,dt2) having relations to each other.
Now i want to convert the Dataset to a nested json string.

Option1:

```
string myresult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds);
```

Using this creates a non-nested json string.
Result: Displays all values from dt1 first, then all values from dt2

Option:2:

```
string myresult = ds.GetXml();
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(myresult);
return (JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc));
```

When i use this i get a nested json string but int-values are displayed as string-values ("Id": 1 is displayed as "Id": "1")

I think [Convert Dataset with Relation to JSON string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917320/convert-dataset-with-relation-to-json-string) is a similar issue - the answer creates the same result like option 2

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna look into this one

```
System.web.script.serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Using this creates an error:
{"A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Globalization.CultureInfo'."}

and ignoring referenceloop creates option 1 output